# javascript, pick a random hex color between a start and end color

Tags: javascript, colors

IS there any quick way of accomplishing this?

For example the start color #EEEEEE and end color #FFFFFF would make something like #FEFFEE.

Comment: Would it work to convert to HSLA, then pick H, S, L, and A between the two ranges independently, then convert back to hex?

Comment: you could use an equivalent for the php hexdec function and actually calculate hex colors like numbers: [http://phpjs.org/functions/hexdec/](http://phpjs.org/functions/hexdec/)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Of course the hex is encoded as a number but for it to make any kind of sense, you have to first extract the rgb components :

```
function rgb(string){
    return string.match(/\w\w/g).map(function(b){ return parseInt(b,16) })
}
var rgb1 = rgb("#EEEEEE");
var rgb2 = rgb("#FFFFFF");
```

Then simply take an intermediate of all components :

```
var rgb3 = [];
for (var i=0; i<3; i++) rgb3[i] = rgb1[i]+Math.random()*(rgb2[i]-rgb1[i])|0;
```

And finally rebuild the color as a standard hex string :

```
var newColor = '#' + rgb3
    .map(function(n){ return n.toString(16) })
    .map(function(s){ return "00".slice(s.length)+s}).join('');
```

Note that in order to get better results, depending on your goal, for example if you want to keep the luminosity, using a different [color space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_color_spaces_and_their_uses) than RGB (say HSL or HSV) might be useful.

Answer (score 1):

[d3](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Quantitative-Scales) does this extremely well by creating colour scales:

```
var color = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([-1, 0, 1])
    .range(["red", "white", "green"]);

color(-1)   // "#ff0000" red
color(-0.5) // "#ff8080" pinkish
color(0)    // "#ffffff" white
color(0.5)  // "#80c080" getting greener
color(0.7)  // "#4da64d" almost there..
color(1)    // "#008000" totally green!
```

Comment: how to we specify this for bar plots. I may have 10 datapoints or 100 data point...how to handle this varying data range

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question in the right way, you want each digit to be in the same range. Do you mean each digit or each component (color channel). For each digit see [my fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/X3eMW/)

The key is:

```
for(var i = 0;i < 6; i++) {
    color += (Math.floor(Math.random() * (end-start+1)) + start).toString(16);
}
```

with start and end from 0 to 15

or each channel:

```
for(var i = 0;i < 3; i++) {
    color += (Math.floor(Math.random() * (end-start+1)) + start).toString(16);
}
```

with start and end between 0 and 255

Comment: Are you sure he doesn't want 0xF0 as a value between 0xEE and 0xFF? That would be surprising.

Comment: not sure, as his question is not asked very precise, but according to his example after a few test runs with (start = 13 end = 15) it gave me #feefef #ffeeff #eeffff #fffeef #fffffe

Comment: what example do you mean? I can't see any link posted by the asker anywhere around this question.

Comment: The example I gave in my fiddle generates those colors, referring to his question "_...#EEEEEE and end color #FFFFFF would make something like #FEFFEE._"

Comment: I don't think you can use the results of your interpretation as a proof that that interpretation is correct :-)

Comment: I upvoted the answer of @dystroy , nevertheless I tried to answer the question, according to my interpretation of it. Sorry if I was wrong, but if people nowadays give poor descriptions to the question it is hard for SO new comers to give appropriate answers in an small amount of time. Just trying to do my best to help...

Answer (score 0):

[Denys Séguret's version](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23277879/295783) in ES6

```js
const rgb = string => string.match(/\w\w/g).map(b => parseInt(b, 16))
const rgbrnd = (rgb1, rgb2) => {
  const rgb3 = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) rgb3[i] = rgb1[i] + Math.random() * (rgb2[i] - rgb1[i]) | 0;
  return '#' + rgb3
    .map(n => n.toString(16).padStart(2, '0'))
    .join('');
};


const rgb1 = rgb("#00FF00"); // green 
const rgb2 = rgb("#FF0000"); // red
console.log(rgbrnd(rgb1, rgb2))
```

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
function getRandomColor(start, end){
    var min=parseInt(start.replace("#",""), 16);
    var max=parseInt(end.replace("#",""), 16);
    return "#"+Math.floor((Math.random() * (max - min) + min)).toString(16).toUpperCase();
}
```

Here is a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uN8bn/) to play with.

Comment: It doesn't take a intermediate for each composant.

Comment: Who upvoted this has no idea of what makes a color... this gives colors like #F493F1...

Comment: It does, what the TO wanted: a *random* color. Nothing more or less.