# is it possible to choose a random color from a gradient or a range between two colors?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I got an example of two range of colours, which is #ed1f7f and #6c52a2, is there any possible way I can put some elements with some random colours within the range of those two?

Comment: You could convert the colors to HSV or HSL color space, and then interpolate each of the 3 color components

Comment: Related: [javascript, pick a random hex color between a start and end color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23277585/javascript-pick-a-random-hex-color-between-a-start-and-end-color)

Comment: Okay.. changing it to HSL works like butter.. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially, you do a [linear interpolation in 3D space](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1965497/how-can-i-find-a-random-position-between-two-points).

There is a nice formula to do that:

```
(1-u)*p_1+u*p_2

where u is a random float between 0 and 1
p_1, p_2 are the co-ordinate of the points
```

For colour specifically, if you use an array to store the colour components:

```
function interpolate(u, c1, c2) {
    return c1.map((a, i) => Math.floor((1-u) * a + u * c2[i]));
}
function pickRandom(u, c1, c2) {
    return interpolate(Math.random(), c1, c2);
}
```

If your colour value is in hex notation you'll need to convert them to numeric rgb or hsl first.